# Is it secure to add PHP Form processor in template?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I'm trying to build a custom form without any extension. And to do this I need to add a PHP form processor file in template `templates/mytemplate/form/process.php`

Is it secure to add and call form processor from the Joomla! Template?

Comment: Lets exclude security for a moment....it's simply the *wrong* place to put the form process code. Template is design, and design only. You should use an 3rd party extension or try building your own extension.

Comment: It helps! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you have in the `process.php` file, and whether you are using proper filtering for user input or not.

Having said that, maintaining such a form is not fun, especially if the one maintaining it is not you. I suggest you use a real form builder such as RS Forms, which allows you to do almost anything form-building and form-processing wise.